# Unity constrainting type\instance resolving in child container

Tags: .net, unity-container

How i can restrict type resolving in child unityContainer ?

E.g

```
internal interface ITestInterface
{}
public class Test:ITestInterface
{}
class A
{
    public A(ITestInterface testInterface)
    {    
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var container = new UnityContainer();

        Test test = new Test();
        container.RegisterInstance<ITestInterface>(test);

        var childContainer = container.CreateChildContainer();
        //shoudl resolved normally
        container.Resolve<A>();
        //should throw exception!
        //because i want restrict resolving ITestInterface instance from parent container!            
        childContainer.Resolve<A>();                       
    }
}
```

Comment: You want the derived container have it's own set of registrations? So that some classes can only be derived from the parent container?

Comment: it not derived container it is child container. It important difference

Comment: Yes, I mean child container. Sorry for confusion. So you want the child container to have it's own set of registrations?

Comment: by default child container ovveride any registrations and if it not found registration is own set it searches types in parent container..

Comment: i want force my parent container don't resolve certain types in child container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really the wrong thing to do. Seriously reconsider your container hierarchies, you may not want a hierarchy at all here.

However, if you're dead set on doing this, you can fake it. Reregister the type in the child with an InjectionFactory that throws an exception.

```
childContainer.RegisterType<A>(
    new InjectionContructor(c => throw new InvalidOperationException(
        "No type A for you!"))));
```